Using field variable to calculate a value for order by clause (jOOQ)
I am using jOOQ with Kotlin and PostgreSQL.
I have defined a field as a variable.
I want to use this variable both in the SELECT statement and in the ORDER BY clause.
However, in the ORDER BY clause i use it to calculate the value to order by.
jOOQ runs into a problem here because it only uses the fields name which would work if i would only sort by the field and not use it to calculate a new field.
Here is a minimal example:
val field = ACTOR.ACTOR_ID.`as`("my_actor_id")
ctx
    .select(ACTOR.LAST_NAME, field)
    .from(ACTOR)
    .orderBy(field.plus(1))
    .fetch()

This throws an exception:
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select
  "public"."actor"."last_name",
  "public"."actor"."actor_id" as "my_actor_id"
from "public"."actor"
order by ("my_actor_id" + ?)]; ERROR: column "my_actor_id" does not exist

If i only sort by the field i stored as a variable like this everything works as expected:
ctx
    .select(ACTOR.LAST_NAME, field)
    .from(ACTOR)
    .orderBy(field)
    .fetch()

because this query, which uses the fields name, is valid:
select
  "public"."actor"."last_name",
  "public"."actor"."actor_id" as "my_actor_id"
from "public"."actor"
order by "my_actor_id"

I would have expected, that jOOQ realizes, that the field is not used by its own in the ORDER BY clause and thus the definition of the field has to be used instead of its alias.
My current workaround looks like this:
val fieldWithoutAlias = ACTOR.ACTOR_ID
val field = fieldWithoutAlias.`as`("my_actor_id")
ctx
    .select(ACTOR.LAST_NAME, field)
    .from(ACTOR)
    .orderBy(fieldWithoutAlias.plus(1))
    .fetch()

Is there a better way to tell jOOQ to use the field definition instead of the alias?
Am i correct in my assumption, that jOOQ does not detect that the field definition has to be used here instead of its name?

As of jOOQ 3.19, there's a known issue for this topic:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3575

You've already found the workaround, so use that for now.

I would have expected, that jOOQ realizes, that the field is not used by its own in the ORDER BY clause and thus the definition of the field has to be used instead of its alias.

This is dialect specific. A lot of dialects support rendering the projection alias in ORDER BY expressions. There isn't a good reason not to, the semantics is clear according to the logical order of SELECT operations in SQL, but obviously, if a dialect is known not to support this syntax, then jOOQ could emulate it by substituting the alias for its definition.
Note, there are also dialects where the inverse is true, e.g. BigQuery!
By default, an alias always renders its alias reference, not its declaration, see also the manual's section about declaration vs reference.

Thank you for the quick answer and additional info.
Very interesting! I did not know that this is a dialect specific feature.
